# json header does not work - php

Tags: php, json, http-headers

i have a webservice and a web interface for registered user. this section allow the user to get their statistics (similar to stack overflow)

- number of views
- number of answers
- number of post
- number of support ticket
  etc...

now this tool i have allow the user to retreive their data in a json format, my problem is the header sent is not working for all the browsers

i have:

```
header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Content-type: text/json');
```

should i remove the expires and cache control?

Comment: The commonly accepted MIME for json is `application/json`.

Comment: thanks @TomvanderWoerdt, can you put this as your answer so i can accept it?

Comment: JSON is typically not a format that works in web browsers, unlike HTML or XML. If you use JSON, then you'd expect a JSON parser to read it, not a browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The commonly accepted MIME for json is `application/json`.

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

See also: [What is the correct JSON content type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/the-right-json-content-type)